# exporting a dependency within npm package

Tags: npm

I have npm package called `mypackage` that is using `@mikro-orm/core` (some node lib).
I want to export `@mikro-orm/core` from `mypackage` to prevent version mismatch.
So in my `mypackage/src/index.ts` I did:

```
export * from '@mikro-orm/core';
```

Can the app that is dependent on `mypackage` import objects from `@mikro-orm/core` without installing it?

Thanks

Comment: While I appreaciate @CTK's answer, this is still kind of painful for packages with multiple entrypoints/subpaths. I've come up short on this myself. Hoping for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar now for one of my projects.
I have a common project that is used in several services.  All of my services use aws-sdk and the common project, and my common project also uses aws-sdk.

Instead of having multiple versions of aws-sdk around, I plan on removing aws-sdk from my services and importing the aws-sdk from the common project.

I start by exporting aws-sdk from my common project in my index.ts:

```
export * as AWS from "aws-sdk";
```

Then just importing AWS from my other services like so:

```
import { AWS } from "@myproject/common";
```

I'm also importing that common project in my package.json for each service:

```
"@myproject/common": "file:../../common"
```